# Not showing modal cookie policy on certain routes

Tags: laravel, cookies, package

I am using `[statikbe/laravel-cookie-consent]` [package](https://github.com/statikbe/laravel-cookie-consent) for cookie policy in my `Laravel` project and I don't want the modal to be shown on certain pages, so I must add the route to `ignored_paths` array in the config file. For a route as `'admin/users'` every thing is fine but for a route as `'admin/user/{id}'` it doesn't work. How can I fix it or how can say all the routes which start with `'/admin'` don't show the cookie policy?

Comment: looks like you would have to adjust their javascript to use a pattern instead of comparing strings exactly

Comment: @lagbox How can I do that?